# Can't make JQuery's .children() selector work

Tags: jquery

**HTML**

```
div id="picksItem1" class="browser-content-item" onclick="navigate('https://ddg.gg',$(this).attr('id'))">
     <div class="browser-content-item-frame"></div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
function navigate(link,item) {
    $(item).children('.browser-content-item-frame').css("width", ($(window).width() / 2) + 80 + "px");
    $(item).children('.browser-content-item-frame').css("height", "320px");

}
```

[Full Context](https://codepen.io/gatesofdawn/full/VzjvQp/) (click thumbnail previews under "Editors' Picks" section)

No errors are reported, but nothing happens.  Logging the $(item).children returns a message about it being empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are not passing the item in the onclick function but a string (id).

change

```
navigate('https://ddg.gg',$(this).attr('id'))
```

to

```
navigate('https://ddg.gg',$(this))
```

In relation to adeneo's comment, indeed a far better approach is adding an event listener

```js
function navigate() {
    var url = $(this).attr("data-href"); //get your url from the div object
    $(this).children('.browser-content-item-frame').css("width", ($(window).width() / 2) + 80 + "px");
    $(this).children('.browser-content-item-frame').css("height", "320px");

}

$("#picksItem1").click(navigate);
```

```css
.browser-content-item-frame {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-href="https://ddg.gg" id="picksItem1" class="browser-content-item" >
     <div class="browser-content-item-frame">click me</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or better, stop using inline javascript

Comment: There would potentially be hundreds of elements like this one.  I'm not sure how I'm supposed to do a click listener for each individual one.

Comment: see my addition in response to @adeneo very true comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the #id of the div, no need to pass a jQuery function into your custom function:

```
<div id="picksItem1" class="browser-content-item" onclick="navigate('https://ddg.gg','#picksItem1')">
```

Do this on both your "picksItem" divs. But a better solution would be to add a 'click' event listener insider your JS, rather than defining it inside your html.

Then you have only one function and can use `this` properly. You can store custom `link` values on a `data-link=''` attribute and access it in your event listener.